# SSH forwarding (SSH_AUTH_SOCK) on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, docker

Does anyone use SSH forwarding on Windows?

It says it should set up `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env var. But this variable is empty.

If I run `start-ssh-agent` command it shows:

```
Found ssh-agent at 3356
Found ssh-agent socket at /tmp/ssh-z8A7Sq092g3X/agent.10484
Identity added: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

`%SSH_AUTH_SOCK%` is available in this shell, but is not available in other shells.

I'm trying to forward  SSH to a Docker container.

Does forwarding work for you even to some servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> %SSH_AUTH_SOCK% is available in this shell, but is not available in other shells.

Environment variables are per-shell, therefore it is not available in the other shells, unless you start them from the first one. This is feature.

> I'm trying to forward SSH to a Docker container.

To forward `ssh-agent` authentication socket, you need to use `-A` switch to `ssh` or `ForwardAgent` option in `ssh_config`.

> Does forwarding work for you even to some servers?

Yes, it does!

Comment: Thanks for the replay. When I start docker build in some shell %SSH_AUTH_SOCK% is not available here. How should I make it available, I just didn't get the workflow of build/starting container where I need to forward ssh keys.

Comment: To forward the authentication agent to `docker`, you need to either `ssh` it, or forward this socket into the docker in different way.

Comment: So ssh forwarding only works while being logged via ssh? I thought they where mapping it (socket) using volumes.

Comment: No. It is a socket as any other. But forwarding it over `ssh` is easiest way to do that.

Comment: Isn't it possible to make %SSH_AUTH_SOCK% available in any shell launched?

Comment: you can't mount the agent socket to docker containers in windows: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/167